# Allow access to WCF based on a group set in web.config

Tags: wcf, iis, authentication, web-config

I have created a WCF service that uses windows authentication and would like to set it so it can only be accessed if the user is in a Windows group. I Currently use the following attribute in code to make this happen

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Domain\MyGroup")]
```

Problem with this is I have to do it on each method and compile if I want to change the group. Is there a way so I can set the group that has access in the config file and for the services as an whole?

I have tried the following in my config file but this does not appear to work

```
<security>
   <authentication>
      <windowsAuthentication authPersistSingleRequest="true" enabled="true"/>
   </authentication>
   <authorization>
      <add accessType="Allow" roles="Domain\MyGroup" /> 
   </authorization>
</security>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I have the config file set like the following

```
<security>
  <authentication>
    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
  <authorization>
    <remove users="*" roles="" verbs="" />
    <remove users="?" roles="" verbs="" />
    <add accessType="Deny" users="?" />
    <add accessType="Allow" roles="Domain\MyGroup" />
  </authorization>
</security>
```

Also had to set

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

And on my class that implements the WCF contract

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

I guess this means Im using ASP authentication rather than WCF but I works for me

Answer (score 0):

The `PrincipalPermission` attribute is from the .NET code access security functionality and isn't related to WCF. A more flexible way to do this if the service is hosted in IIS is shown in this [MSDN post.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx) WCF also supports different custom authentication mechanisms [as described here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650794.aspx)

Comment: You're confusing authentication with authorization. PrincipalPermissionAttribute is concerned with the latter. While it is true that this attribute is part of CAS, you haven't really answered the question.